# Procedure to find propositional formula given by the tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

The propositional formula given by the tree:

[image]

1. $\land \lor x_2 \lor x_1 \lnot x_1 \lnot x_1$
2. $(x_2\lor x_2)\land (x_1\lor x_1)$
3. $(\lnot x_1 \lor x_2)\land (\lnot x_1 \lor x_2)$
4. None of these

---

My attempt :

I googled and I guessed this should be option $(3)\space (\lnot x_1 \lor x_2)\land (\lnot x_1 \lor x_2)$

My question is :

$x_1$ should be right child of $\lnot$ in both subtree?

> Can you explain it, please?

Comment: $\neg$ is a unary operator. In the tree it doesn't belong in a left or right child, because there are no left or right children to begin with.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, exactly. thanks.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, do you like your comment as answer, please answer it.

Comment: It is a PROpositional formula, from proposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Lifting my comment into an answer.)

$\neg$ is a unary operator, and hence does not have "left" and "right" children in a propositional tree. It just has a single child.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.